# Testing function contains an API request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, stripe.net

I'm trying to test my rails application which using Stripe APIs, So I started with models, I'm using Rspec, The model which i want to test is called bank_account.rb inside it there is a function called (create_bank_account) with argument (bank_token) its pseudocode is something like this:

```
def create_bank_account(bank_token)
  # make a Stripe request and save it in local variable
  # save needed data in my bank_account table in my DB
end
```

when i started to test this function, I found that there is an API call inside it, Which is not good, I need my test not to depend on Internet, So after searching I found 'StripeMock` gem, It is useful and i started to use it with Rspec, but I found my self writing a test like this:

```
it 'with valid bank_token` do
  # create a double for bank_account
  # using StripeMock to get a faked response for creating
  # new bank_account
  # expect the doube to receive create_bank_account
  # function and response with saving the data inside the DB
end
```

but after writing this I noticed that I didn't actually run create_bank_account function i faked it, So my questions are:

1- How can i test function that includes API request but run the function it self not faking it?

2- I read a lot about when we use doubles and stubs and what i understood is when a function is not completed, but if the functions is already implemented should i use doubles to avoid something like functions that call APIs?

Comment: You can use stub just the api call not the function in itself. Eg say api call in done by `Sendgrid.send()`, then you can stub that alone by `Sendgrid.stub(:send).with('more_than', 'one_argument')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost:

- Do not create a double for `bank_account`.
- Do not mock/stub `bank_account.create_bank_account`.

If you do either of these things, in a test that is *supposed to be* testing behaviour of `BankAccount#create_bank_account`, then your test is worthless.

(To prove this point, try writing **broken code** in the method. Your tests should obviously *fail*. But if you're mocking the method, everything will remain passing!!)

One way or another, you should **only** be mocking the `stripe` request, i.e. the behaviour at the *boundary* between your application and the internet.

I cannot provide a working code sample without a little more information, but broadly speaking you could refactor your code from this:

```
def create_bank_account(bank_token)
  # make a Stripe request and save it in local variable
  # save needed data in my bank_account table in my DB
end
```

To this:

```
def create_bank_account(bank_token)
  stripe_request = make_stripe_request(bank_token)
  # save needed data in my bank_account table in my DB
end

private

def make_stripe_request(bank_token)
  # ...
end
```

...And then in your test, you can [use `StripeMock`](https://github.com/rebelidealist/stripe-ruby-mock#test-helpers) to *only* fake the response of `BankAccount#make_stripe_request`.

If the code is not so easy to refactor(?!), then stubbing the `Stripe` library directly like this might not be practical. An alternative approach you can always take is use a library like [`webmock`](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock) to simply intercept all HTTP calls.

Comment: Say this is the response format from requesting creating a new [bank account](https://www.ideone.com/I5WUhg), I'm saving `id` and `bank_name` into my DB, Then from your answer should i only test make_stripe_request and not to test create_bank_account? am i right?

Comment: What i mean is i'm testing create_bank_account right? So every line in create_bank_account should run, Is this possible? Or not possible because i don't want to call real server? Thanks

Comment: What is your test actually trying to achieve? I presume it's something like `bank_account.create_bank_account; expect(bank_account.bank_name).to eq("Big Money")`? Again, I need more information to provide a concrete answer, but I strongly suspect it *is* the `BankAccount#create_bank_account` method you should be testing.

Comment: So no; from my answer your tests should only *call* `BankAccount#create_bank-account`, but should only *stub* `BankAccount#make_string_request`.

Comment: And as I suggested above, if you don't want to stub *any* of your code then I'd suggest only mocking the HTTP calls (via webmock) and not the stripe object itself.

Comment: this is the implementation of [create_bank_account](https://www.ideone.com/PNRgDn), In the test i will check on status object if it is "new", Are these information enough? You are saying my test should call create_bank_account but inside it i'm calling `Stripe` server, So calling in my test will fire the API call, If you could write even a pseudo code for the test i will truly appreciate it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158162/discussion-between-tom-lord-and-amr-adel).